# Opening ports with TCP and then reading and writing to them C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tcpclient, tcplistener, networkstream

I am writing a program - call it A - which will open ports in order to communicate with a different program (Eclipse for example) - call it B.

So every time I decide I want to open a new port, I do the following:

1. Create a new TCP listener with a 0 value

   ```
   _listener = new TcpListener((IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 0)
   ```

   so it will open it on an available port.
2. Get the port number which was opened

   ```
   int newp = ((IPEndPoint)_listener.LocalEndpoint).Port
   ```
3. Sent program B info about what port will be opening immediately - to the existing port
4. Perform a blocking call to accept the client

   ```
   TcpClient client =_listener.AcceptTcpClient()
   ```

I can see (with netstat -anb) that the port is "listening" but the connection doesn't seem to be established since the programs are not continuing to communicate.

Also if I try to get the stream in order to write to that port - it fails and throws an exception.

```
NetworkStream stream = _client.GetStream();
stream.Write(...);
```

Thanks so much in advance all!

Comment: Where is the code, where the client connects to the server?

Comment: In a new thread

Comment: in a new thread "where"?  What is the exception?  Exactly what is the question?